# MySQL How To Retrieve Table Name As A Field

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

Im not sure how to exactly word my issue but I will try my best. Im trying to model a database for a driving school. I have a "timeslot" table such that activities such as lessons, tests, and registration interviews can all be linked to a given timeslot for a staff member. One of the queries I am providing is to be able to view a "timetable" of events for a staff member. I have constructed the query and it is working, however it joins data from various other tables, and I would like to see the names of those tables to know what activity the timeslot is reserved for.

[ER Model](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/534/erdu.png/)

The query I perform to check the staff timetable is the following:

```
SELECT Timeslot.*
FROM Timeslot
LEFT JOIN Test
ON Timeslot.Timeslot_ID = Test.Timeslot
LEFT JOIN Interview
ON Timeslot.Timeslot_ID = Interview.Timeslot
LEFT JOIN Lesson
ON Timeslot.Timeslot_ID = Lesson.Timeslot
WHERE Timeslot.Date BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
AND Timeslot.Staff = 1;
```

This works and shows a list of all registered timeslots for a given staff member for the next week. What I would like is a further column which would show what type of activity it is, such as "Lesson", "Interview", or "Test". As you can see, I am currently storing this as a field in the timeslot table, which means that I have to specify this every time I insert a timeslot. I will be normalising the database to 3NF and want to avoid duplication. Is there a way I model this to get the name of the table, I considered using UNIONS and many other things but could use some help.

Many thanks and apologies if this seems a bit vague.
Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My stab at it, if you're keeping the model you've described, would be with a Case statement, like so:

```
Select Timeslot.*,
    Case
        When Test.Timeslot Is Not Null Then 'Test'
        When Interview.Timeslot Is Not Null Then 'Interview'
        When Lesson.Timeslot Is Not Null Then 'Lesson'
    End As ActivityType
From ...
```

Your query would then have an "ActivityType" column at the very end that you could use.

Comment: There's no inner join, so only one of the three can match. Anything else would be a double booking, which would be returned as duplicate rows.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Avoids unnecessary duplication. I was not aware of the case statement, will look into that further. Many thanks

Comment: What difference does it make how many of them produce results? The idea is that between 0 and 3 of them will produce results, and that the rows will be intermixed. The case statement simply determines on a per-row basis which table was joined in. Seems pretty clear to me, so I'm having trouble figuring out what you're talking about.